# Utilizing a string from an array to a function as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use some string from an array and pass it into a function. The string has the same name as a global variable. From there, I want to set the output to the variable name. It is being passed to a slider function where the variable should update upon any changes.

I've tried passing it through [window] or eval(), but it does not work. Ideally, in the createSliders() function, on slide the global var would update.

```
i_current_annual_volume = 1000000;

let sliderArr = [{
   input: "i_current_annual_volume" (or window[i_current_annual_volume]),
   value: 1000000,
   min: 1000,
   max: 10000000,
   step: 1000,
}];

function createSliders() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < sliderArr.length; i++ ){
    let slider_name = "#slider-" + [i + 1];
    let handle_name = "#custom-handle-" + [i + 1];
    let input_field = sliderArr[ i ].input;

    $( slider_name ).slider({
      value: sliderArr[ i ].value,
      min: sliderArr[ i ].min,
      max: sliderArr[ i ].max,
      step: sliderArr[ i ].step,
      create: function() {
        $( handle_name ).text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( handle_name ).text( ui.value );
        input_field = ui.value;
      },
      stop: function(){
        loadNumbers();
      }
    });
  }
};



When I remove the quotes in the sliderArr, the output is 1000000. I need it to be i_current_annual_volume.
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried to use `window`, but you didn't show how you tried to do it. Global variables are properties of the `window` object. See [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Change

```
        input_field = ui.value;
```

to

```
        window[input_field] = ui.value;
```

Comment: Why should he.?

Comment: Added some explanation and a link to a more extensive question.

Comment: @Rob I don't see why this answer wouldn't work. Although the author did mention having tried using `window`, there were no specifics given.

Comment: @Pablo Rob didn't say it wouldn't work. He was just prompting me to add more explanation, rather than just posting the code. Since I frequently make similar comments to others, he caught me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I ended up creating an object array {} and passing the variable as string. That wound up being a simpler solution.